# javascript - how to get date format from string date

Tags: javascript, angular, date, format

How can I get date format (for example: `DD/MM/YYYY`) from already formatted date (for example: `1/9/2021`). Also can I somehow achieve not to swap US Date and NOT US Date (`DD/MM/YYYY` vs. `MM/DD/YYYY`).

I'm using Angular project (in case there is a Angular solution)

Comment: You can't, which is why `new Date('31/08/2021')` will return an invalid date in most (all?) implementations. The only reliable way to parse timestamps is if you know the format beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't reliably determine the format that a user inputs a date string based on system settings, even if you had access to them, because the user might input the value in a different format. E.g. in Britain it's common to use day/month/year, but if you check out the date on [The Times newspaper](https://www.thetimes.co.uk) you'll see something like "Sunday September 5 2021".

That's one reason why date pickers are used, however many users still prefer to enter dates manually and often find date pickers annoying.

Anyway, it seemed like a bit of fun to determine the localised format that [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) produces for the default system language. This is of course totally unreliable, whatever. :-)

This works because [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) returns the parts in an array in the order associated with the language, along with the separators.

```js
function getDateFormat(lang) {
  let d = new Date(2021,0,20);      
  let format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(lang,{
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric'
  }).formatToParts(d).reduce((acc,part) => {
    acc += part.type == 'literal'? part.value : part.type;
    return acc;
  }, '');
  
  return format;
}

['default',
 'en-GB',
 'en-US',
 'en-CA',
 'nl-BX',
 'ar'].forEach(lang => {
   let langDefault = lang == 'default'? new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default').resolvedOptions().locale : null;
   console.log('Lang ' + lang + (langDefault? ' (' + langDefault + ')':'') +
     ' format ' + getDateFormat(lang) + '.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **moment.js** to parse date like:

```js
import moment from "moment";

const newDate = moment("1/9/2021", "MM/DD/YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
// newDate = 09/01/2021
```

Comment: I need to get the format from already formatter datestring. I don't have problems with formatting the Date. I have datestring which looks like that ```1/9/2021``` and I need to get the type of formatting which has been used, so the result would be ```DD/MM/YYYY```.

Comment: Where does this formatted date comes from ?

Comment: I need to get the format depending on user's local settings (if his system is using ```DD/MM/YYYY``` or ```MM/DD/YYYY```). When I find out his system is using ```DD/MM/YYYY``` I format the given date by the format I received.